# How do I give event registrants one of four prices but allow admins to select a free option for guests?

Tags: civievent, forms

I have an event signup form where I have four different price options. I have made this a mandatory field in order to require that registrants select one price option. However, when I as an admin user sign up a guest or volunteer, I would like there to be another option that does not cost anything.

Is there a way of doing this without also offering this option to the regular attendee? I cannot figure out how.

The workaround that we have is to add an additional field for admins with a negative amount to reduce the payment down to 0. This is not a great solution.

Comment: To clarify - you're using price sets, and you want to make a price field that's mandatory and publicly visible, and you want a single price field option to be admin-only?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am using price sets. It is possible that an admin will take  payment offline and want to have one of the publicly available options too.

Comment: I do the negative amount visible only to admins and this works fine for me

Comment: @zeiddev I don't understand why the use of an admin only field with a negative amount is considered to be "not a great solution". Does it not fully meet your needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have accomplished this using the [CiviDiscount](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount-extension) module. It works well. You'll just need to create a code that offers a 100% discount and then only share this code with people whom you deem qualified for free registration.

Comment: Seconded. CiviDiscount manages this quite well. Define the discount code to something memorable for the admin, but hard for anyone else to guess.

Answer (score 2):

CiviDiscount will work well for the use case. Another approach is to create a second price field that has visibility set to Admin.

This is the help for the field:

Fields with 'Public' visibility will be displayed on your Event Information page AND will be available in the online registration (self-service) form. For some events you may want to allow staff to select special options with special pricing and / or discounts (using negative price set field values). Select 'Admin' visibility for these Price Fields. They will only be included when staff or volunteers are registering participants from the back-office 'Register Event Participants' screen.